# GUI Display Layout same for all screens Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

Problem is that If i create something on Windows and test same thing on Android Samsung S3 Gui is shows different widgets at different places . For example

1.I created a widget set its size as 800,600
2.Include a label with size 100,100
3. put it at position 700,10 so it should be visible at lower right corner .

This works ok on windows test environment but when i move code to Samsung S3 using kivy launcher it dosent show label at same position .

I read about matix doc on http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html and used following in the code

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_METRICS_DENSITY'] = '1'
os.environ['KIVY_DPI'] = '96'
```

which was the value in Windows but it dosent seem to work .orifginal values of these in Samsung S3 was 
KIVY_METRICS_DENSITY =2
KIVY_DPI = 320
Window.size = 1028X728 (i think )

Then i added dp to the values of position and sizes but still it is same on Android . 
I know i am missing something . Can someone advice ?

Below is the Sample code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import os
os.environ['KIVY_METRICS_DENSITY'] = '1'
os.environ['KIVY_DPI'] = '96'

class Container(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Container, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = '800dp','600dp'
        label = Label(text="Am i A Label ?")
        label.size = '100dp','100dp'
        label.pos = '700dp','10dp'
        self.add_widget(label)

class MyJB(App):
    def build(self):

        parent = Container()
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJB().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the code is doing exactly what you told it to; placing the label at a specific position in pixels. In the default desktop window this happens to be the bottom left, but on another device (or after resizing the window) it could be anywhere, depending on the resolution of the display.

You should instead use layouts, so that everything is set proportionally and will adjust to different screen shapes. For instance, you could use an AnchorLayout to place the label in the bottom right.

Comment: I tried this with anchor layout and even with grid but i could not find how to do it because in my real bigger program i have many such widgets which i need to put on a container widget ... please have a look at my question which i created on anchor layouts <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155905/anchor-layout-to-show-many-widgets-in-a-screen-at-relative-positions>

Comment: Might look newbie question to you but but i raised a similar question on gridlayout . <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156023/is-it-possible-in-kivy-gridlayout-to-specify-a-particular-grid-for-a-particular>

Comment: Also Is it possible to do this without your using layouts and changing finding resolution of different screens and multiplying the resolution values somehow to find a relative position of widget in that screen ?

Comment: Of course you can do it without layouts, but you're literally just reinventing them with your suggestion.

Comment: I didnt get ? If we can do it without Layout , How can we do it ? How to keep the screen same in all devices ?

Comment: Looks like i can do it by using a callback on window resize event ... :)