# Anchor Layout to show many widgets in a screen at relative positions

Tags: python, kivy

I want to show in a button and a label in a widget at left,center position and right,bottom without using .kv code . Here is  my code and i am not able to figure out how to do it  Can someone give advice  ?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Container(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Container, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        btn = Button(text='Hello World',anchor_x='right',anchor_y='bottom')
        self.add_widget(btn)

        lbl = Label(text="Am i a Label ?",anchor_x='left',anchor_y='center')
        self.add_widget(lbl)


class MyJB(App):
    def build(self):

        parent = Container()

        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJB().run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AnchorLayout` aligns all widgets to a given point, not each widget to its own point. If you want widgets anchored in different locations, you need to use multiple `AnchorLayout`s. You also probably want to specify `size` and `size_hint` on either the `AnchorLayout` or the content widgets.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Container(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Container, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        anchor_rb = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right', anchor_y='bottom')
        btn = Button(text='Hello World', size=(100, 100), size_hint=(None, None))
        anchor_rb.add_widget(btn)
        self.add_widget(anchor_rb)

        anchor_lc = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='left', anchor_y='center')
        lbl = Label(text="Am i a Label ?", size=(100, 100), size_hint=(None, None))
        anchor_lc.add_widget(lbl)
        self.add_widget(anchor_lc)


class MyJB(App):
    def build(self):

        parent = Container()

        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJB().run()
```

Personally, I find kv to be cleaner than manual widget creation, and it helps provide a definite separation between the UI and behavior.

kv version:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

root = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'

        Button:
            text: 'Hello World'
            size: 100, 100
            size_hint: None, None

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'center'

        Label:
            text: 'Am i a Label ?'
            size: 100, 100
            size_hint: None, None
''')

class MyJB(App):
    def build(self):
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyJB().run()
```

Comment: Of course, you avoid creation of functions to events, also avoid using `with` with (in example) the `canvas:`, and the `add_widget()` function. At least i noticed those extras. Kv lang is magnific.